# How to calculate output impedance of switching regulator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, impedance-matching

If I consider a buck converter where in 24 volts, L =100 μH, capacitor 47 μF. Then converter will operate at 400 kHz. How do I calculate the output impedance of the converter?

Comment: Impossible to say without a controller and switching mode (DCM or CCM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has feedback to control the duty cycle, the output impedance will be defined by the loop, and could be zero, or slightly positive or negative, or near infinite if controlled as a current output.

If you mean the instantaneous impedance, you'll also need the duty cycle, switching devices resistance, inductor loss ...

Answer (score 0):

Laboratory Answer:

You may want to use this instruments AP310 Analyzer by Ridley Engineering

https://ridleyengineering.com/hardware/ap310-analyzer/intro-ap-analyzer.html

It will inject a small signal, without modifying the BIAS point of the circuit, in the output loop of your converter and it will measure the output impedance.

---

Theoretical Answer:

Christophe Basso wrote many books and articles about the output impedance of power converters in the Laplace's domain:

https://www.onsemi.com/company/news-media/blog/author/christophe-basso

This in an interesting Basso's article to start from:

https://www.electronicdesign.com/content/article/21187698/biasing-the-tl431-for-improved-output-impedance